# How to use a naming context to find de Bruijn indices of free variables?

Tags: lambda-calculus

In "Types and Programming Languages", section 6.1.2 they talk about a *naming context* used to number free variables in lambda expressions.  Using the example scheme they've provided, both `λx.xb` and `λx.xx` will have their de Bruijn representation as `λ.00` when they're clearly different terms.  How does this work?

Comment: What makes you think the representation of the first one would be `λ.00`. I don't think the first can be represented at all since `b` isn't bound anywhere.

Comment: In the section I mentioned, they talk about how free variables can be represented using a _naming context_.

Comment: Ah, I see now. I'll write an answer shortly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As you mentioned the book uses a naming context which maps `n` free variables to the numbers from `0` to `n-1`. However if you look closely at the examples in the book, you'll notice that it doesn't use those numbers directly to represent the variables. For example it represents `λw. y w` as `λ. 4 0` even though the mapping for `y` is 3, not 4.

What's happening here is that he adds the nesting depth of the variable to the number. I.e. if a free variable `v` is nested in `d` lambdas, it gets the index `Γ(v)+d`, not just `Γ(v)`.

So in your example using the context `Γ {b -> 0}` `λx.xb` would be represented as `λ. 0 1`, not `λ. 0 0`. Thus there's no ambiguity.

Comment: I created a [web based interpreter](http://pure-fn.appspot.com/about) for a simpler index based method in an effort to learn the workings of the Lambda Calculus.  I would appreciate your feedback on it.